# MySQL Select The Most Recent Incoming or Outgoing Messages of Distinct Users

Tags: mysql

I have a table structure where I keep records of the messages sent and received like below;

[image: Database table structure]

member_id1 is the sender and member_id2 is the receiver.

Now what I'm trying to achieve is to get the rows with the most recent messages of the user who has the member_id of 3. The result should contain only 2 rows with the message ids of 2 and 4, as 2 is the last message between the user with the member_id of 3 and the user with the member_id of 2, and 4 is the only message between the user with the member_id of 3 and the user with the member_id of 1 yet.

The result shouldn't contain the rows with the message_id of 3 for it has nothing to do with the user who has the member_id of 3, and the message_id of 1 because it has been overdated by the message with the message_id of 2.

Hope I've made my question clear for people who can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured out the right answer for my own question. Although I'm not quite sure, it seems to work great. For those who need a solution to such a problem; give this a try:

```
SELECT m1.* 
  FROM table_name m1 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(senddate) AS senddate, 
                     IF(member_id2 = 3, member_id1, member_id2 ) AS user 
                FROM table_name 
               WHERE (member_id1 = 3 AND delete1=0) OR 
                     (member_id2 = 3 AND delete2=0) 
              GROUP BY user) m2 
         ON m1.senddate = m2.senddate AND 
           (m1.member_id1 = m2.user OR m1.member_id2 = m2.user) 
     WHERE (member_id1 = 3 AND delete1=0) OR 
           (member_id2 = 3 AND delete2=0) 
   ORDER BY m1.senddate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit fuzzy but from what I understand your looking for this?

```
 SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE member_id2 = 3 ORDER BY senddate DESC;
```

Comment: Hi Pablo..actually it's not that easy. Because the user can either be the sender or the receiver, which means the query should look not only at the column member_id2 but also member_id1.

Comment: IN that case
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE member_id2 = 3 OR member_id1 = 3 ORDER BY senddate DESC;

Comment: But that would get all the rows which include the member_id 3. We don't want the query to get the overdated rows, we just want the recent ones per addressee.

Comment: Oh then I must say it was quite hard to understand from the text but congratz on fixing it!

Answer (score 0):

You could use UNION to combine them

```
 (SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE member_id2 = 3  ORDER BY senddate DESC limit 1)
union 
 (SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE member_id1 = 3  ORDER BY senddate DESC limit 1)
```

or if you need to get the latest sent/received for every member you could inner join a query that gets the max senddate for each:

```
select * from table_name t1 inner join 
(
 select member_id1, null as member_id2, max(senddate) as senddate 
 from table_name group by member_id1
 UNION
 select null as member_id1, member_id2, max(senddate) as senddate 
 from table_name group by member_id2
) r ON (t1.member_id1 = r.member_id1 OR t1.member_id2 = r.member_id2) 
AND t1.senddate = r.senddate
```

Comment: Hi Patrick64.. your query returns the message ids 4,1,2,3,2,1 respectively. As you can see, not only it gets the ones it shouldn't but also duplicates the ones it should get.

Comment: What about the first query? That's the on that I was hoping would answer your question. I provided the second query just to show how you can get all the latest sent/received messages for all members so I would expect it to return duplicates.

Comment: The first query only returns 2 results since it's limited and the results are the last messages sent and received by the user with the member_id of 3. What we'd like to achieve is to get the whole set of "last" messages sent and received by the user with the member_id of 3 to/from any members that have a messaging history with the user.